# Blender Docs Misleading? 'Invalid Keyword' Error with Inherited Properties

Tags: python, properties

[Property](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Property.html#property-bpy-struct), alongside having several subclasses (like [BoolProperty](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BoolProperty.html#boolproperty-property)), has a number of property definitions, such as [is_library_editable](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Property.html#bpy.types.Property.is_library_editable).
According to my understanding of class inheritance, children of a class inherit all properties of the parent. Indeed, the subclasses all include a list of [Inherited Properties](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BoolProperty.html#bpy.types.BoolProperty.bl_rna_get_subclass_py) that show all property definitions from Property.

However, when attempting to define a property using one of these Inherited Properties, it results in an 'invalid keyword argument' error.

```
beans: BoolProperty(
    is_library_editable=True,
    default=False)

#  TypeError: 'is_library_editable' is an invalid keyword argument for BoolProperty()
```

This issue arises despite Property.icon being listed as one of the Inherited Properties of BoolProperty. Am I overlooking something or are the Docs misleading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is a difference between the class `bpy.types.BoolProperty` ([docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BoolProperty.html)) and the function `bpy.props.BoolProperty` ([docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.BoolProperty)).

There is no reason to expect the keyword arguments you can pass to `bpy.props.BoolProperty` to correspond exactly to the properties on the class `bpy.types.BoolProperty`. `bpy.props.BoolProperty` is a regular function and can take whatever arguments it wants. You can read its docs if you want to know what arguments you can pass.

Comment: I read the docs, it told me BoolProperty Inherits `Property.is_library_editable`. That's why I call it misleading. You can't say there's 'no reason' to expect this to work when it's shown in the docs. If you can't use `is_library_editable` in a BoolProperty then it has no place being in the BoolProp's docs.

Comment: `bpy.types.BoolProperty` does inherit `is_library_editable`. This has zero effect on what arguments you can pass to the unrelated function `bpy.props.BoolFunction`.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you for clearing this up for me. You can see where I got confused. Is it possible to set a BoolProp to be library_editible in an addon or is types.Bool really just for internal stuff?

Comment: Try passing `options={'LIBRARY_EDITABLE'}` to `bpy.prop.BoolProperty`.

Comment: To iterate the `options` parameter is supposed to be a set of strings which you can find in https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/property_flag_items.html#rna-enum-property-flag-items